# Escape characters appearing in incoming message in Mule

Tags: mule

My mule application polls XML file from an external endpoint, processes the XML file using XPath expressions, and forwards the payload to appropriate flows for processing.

I am testing the flows by providing the below XML file as inbound message using SoapUI or Mozilla post:

`<Employee><Applicant empid="1" firstname="simon" surname="O&#39;Brien"/></Employee>`

I am receiving the XML file inside mule flow as below which is perfect and the way I want:

`<Employee><Applicant empid="1" firstname="simon" surname="O'Brien"/></Employee>`

But when I poll the same XML file from external endpoint, escape characters are still appearing in incoming message:

eg. eg. `<Employee><Applicant empid="1" firstname="simon" surname="O&#39;Brien"/></Employee>`

I want to receive message with apostrophe (') in place of (').

Can you please advise where I am wrong? Why it is behaving differently for external endpoint and SoapUI?

Comment: You need to provide your Mule config file .. It will be difficult to detect the issue without seeing your Mule Config

Comment: You're not showing your flows, so when you say "I am receiving the xml file inside mule flow as below which is perfect and the way I want" we have no idea what you mean. Is this in a logger? In a component?

Comment: Also, why is having `&#39;` a problem? In XML, this is strictly equivalent to having the apostrophe so for any system parsing this data, this should not make a difference.

Comment: And what Mule version are you using?